# Manipulate all strings in a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of URLs in a table column, like the following:

```
<tr>
  <td class="impression_referer">http://www.google.fi/search?hl=en&amp;q=http+header+referer&amp;btnG=Google-search&amp;meta=&amp;aq=f&amp;oq=</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="impression_referer">http://www.facebook.com</td>
</tr>
```

I have a .js file where I at the bottom call all functions for my app, among others the function that should manipulate the above strings:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  cleanUpUrls();
});
```

The code I have to manipulate the strings look like the following:

```
var matches = url.match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);
var domain = matches && matches[1];
```

How should I write my code in the `cleanUpUrls()` function such that I update all the mentioned strings upon page load?

Comment: You're asking how to loop over _Nodes_ with a _class_ token of `impression_referer`?

Comment: Yes. And I'm unsure on how to go about doing this in the most efficient manner when the final result is to update the `DOM` - what kind of `loop`, what kind of `collection`, what kind of `replace` method. I understand that this is an everyday task for web devs, but for me it's not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("td.impression_referer").text(function(i, val) {
    var matches = val.match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);
    return matches ? matches[1] : val;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ht9HC/

Using `$("td.impression_referer")` will select all td elements with the `impression_referer` class. The [`.text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) can be used to get or set the text of an html element. If you pass a callback function to `.text()` your function will be called once per element, with the existing text value passed as a parameter, and the value you return will be set as the new text - you don't have to manually code your own loop because jQuery handles that for you behind the scenes.

Comment: +1 I didn't know you can pass a callback function to `text()` this way. Awesome.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov - Pretty much all of the jQuery methods that get and set something allow a callback, including `.html()`, `.prop()`, `.css()`, etc.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. (The solution, the explanation, the ternary operation.)